# Is it possible to mass-update broken URLs to IndianScriptures.com with HinduScriptures.in?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, sources-and-citations

There are currently about [230 posts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3Aindianscriptures.com) (both questions and answers) that cite the website [IndianScriptures.com](http://IndianScriptures.com). The site itself is active but it doesn't take the reader directly to the linked chapter/topic/PDF.

E.g., clicking on [this URL](http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30601/79_chapter_30.pdf) from the [very first answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2475) to cite this website just takes you to the home page:

[http://www.**indian**scriptures.**com**/Content/Articles/PDFs/30601/79_chapter_30.pdf](http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30601/79_chapter_30.pdf)

This can be easily fixed by changing the URL to:

[http://www.**hindu**scriptures.**in**/Content/Articles/PDFs/30601/79_chapter_30.pdf](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30601/79_chapter_30.pdf)

Can SE staff mass-update these URLs for us without generating a ton of updates to the Active queue?

Comment: There's indeed a tool for this, I'll ping someone from staff who knows about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the url replacements have been made.

Comment: Thanks for making the time to fix this!